# Unable to launch Aptana studio

Tags: ide, aptana, aptana3

When i started my aptana today, it could no tbe launced.Below is the error which is diplayed in aptana studio 3 workspace/.metadata/log

```
  !SESSION 2011-10-25 10:16:43.728 -----------------------------------------------
  eclipse.buildId=unknown
  java.version=1.6.0_24
  java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
  BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_IN
 Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86

 This is a continuation of log file /home/brijendra/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/.metadata    /.bak_0.log
 Created Time: 2011-10-25 10:16:46.189
  !SESSION 2011-10-25 10:16:43.728 -----------------------------------------------
  eclipse.buildId=unknown
  java.version=1.6.0_24
  java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
  BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_IN
  Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86

  !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2011-10-25 10:16:46.189
    !MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session;           refreshing workspace to recover changes.

  !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2011-10-25 10:16:46.399
  !MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle                          org.eclipse.core.resources (294).
   !STACK 0
   org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in     org      .eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:806)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:755)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:370)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:284)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:417)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:265)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:106)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:453)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:393)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:33)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:466)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an Eclipse bug, and you can fix it by following the steps here:

http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Errors+While+Starting+Studio